# Why GRIDVIEW records are showing two times in a single gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 3 tasks:

1. Records should not repeat as showing like that image. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBecZ.png)
2. When I click the button, It has to fetch the entire row records and the index of that particular row,
3. After clicking that button, I have to insert some records in the next row where user click the button.

For example: Totally 10 rows of records is in gridview. If user click second row button, it has to fetch the entire row details, index value of row and then insert 5 five rows of records from third row.

This is my code:
Sample.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

Sample.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
            bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
            bfield.DataField = "Name";
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);

            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            tfield.HeaderText = "Country";
            GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);

            tfield = new TemplateField();
            tfield.HeaderText = "Id";
            GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);
            //BindGrid();
        }
        this.BindGrid();
    }

private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txtCountry = new TextBox();
            txtCountry.ID = "txtCountry";
            txtCountry.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Country"].ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtCountry);

            Button lnkView = new Button();
            lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
            lnkView.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Id"].ToString();
            lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;
            lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Id"].ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lnkView);
        }
    }

    protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button lnkView = (sender as Button);
        GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
        string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;
        string name = row.Cells[0].Text;
        string country = (row.FindControl("txtCountry") as TextBox).Text;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Id: " + id + " Name: " + name + " Country: " + country + "')", true);
    }
```

The most important thing is: I should get index of that row and insert the records between two records.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your duplicate record concern:  there's a property on `GridView` controls called `AutoGenerateColumns`.  It defaults to `true`.

When it is true, all the columns/fields/properties in the data source will automatically appear as columns in the results.  If you then add columns, those columns will appear in addition to (and after) the ones that are automatically generated.

This is easy to fix:  change the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
     OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"       
     AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>
```

If other problems are occurring, ask a separate question for those.